# Not a tidy code but a mess when download files?

Tags: php, file, tidy

sometimes when i download files they look a horrible mess:
eg. i've:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="art-contentLayout">
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar1.php'); ?>
<div class="art-content">
.
.
.
```

but when i download it looks:

```
<?php get_header(); ?><div class="art-contentLayout"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . /sidebar1.php'); ?><div class="art-content">...
```

and sometimes because of this i get php errors.
why this happens? how can i avoid of such occurences?
Thanks

---

PS: OS: Win 7, FTPclient: Filezilla, Editor: Notepad++, text wrapping is checked in editor, and i said SOMETIMES it happens

Comment: Download from what? Anyway, configure your text editor to handle line endings properly.

Comment: Maybe the software you use to view the file and to open the file you downloaded differ, they may be handling newlines differently. Normal text processors can handle all types of newlines (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r` depending on the platform) so that you always get visual newlines, some software doesn't.

Comment: Notepad destroys line endings. Try Wordpad

Comment: Which php errors? And use real IDE. There are enough free

Comment: OS: Win 7, FTPclient: Filezilla, Editor: Notepad++, text wrapping is checked in editor, and i said SOMETIMES it happens

Answer (score 1):

Read this about the history of newline characters (mostly LF vs. CRLF):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

In your case, you just need to find a better text editor to use that will preserve the line endings and show you the file properly.

Comment: Notepad++ has an option "Show end of lines". after enabling it, all the lines ends with CRLF symbol.